# regex with in-line captures for all lines until specified line text value/ custom EOF marker reached

Tags: c#, regex

I have some indented text that looks like this:

```
Foo
    Bar
    Fizz
Buzz
EndOfData
Foo
    Bar
    Fizz
Buzz
```

I'd like to capture the leading white-space and the remainder of the line, for each line, but only until `EndOfData` is reached.

I can capture the white-space and remainder using `^( *)(.*)$`, but I can't work out how to stop the regex from processing beyond the `EndOfData` line.

I'm expecting 4 main matches, each with 2 sub-matches.

Comment: What a strange task for a regex. See [`(?<!^EndOfData\r?\n(?s:.*?))^(?!EndOfData)( *)(.*)$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5eEndOfData%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3fs%3a.*%3f%29%29%5e%28%3f!EndOfData%29%28+*%29%28.*%29%24&i=Foo%0d%0a++++Bar%0d%0a++++Fizz%0d%0aBuzz%0d%0aEndOfData%0d%0aFoo%0d%0a++++Bar%0d%0a++++Fizz%0d%0aBuzz&o=m).

Comment: Do you need something like above?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/JljGB9

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you may get the first index of the `EndOfData` line and then use your regex to grab the data you need:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "Foo\r\n    Bar\r\n    Fizz\r\nBuzz\r\nEndOfData\r\nFoo\r\n    Bar\r\n    Fizz\r\nBuzz";
        var res = Regex.Matches(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("\nEndOfData\r\n")), @"^(\p{Zs}*)(.*)\r$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => new[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value });
        foreach (var v in res)
                Console.WriteLine("Group 1: '{0}', Group 2: '{1}'", v[0], v[1]);
    }
}
```

See the C# demo.

If you really want to play with regex, I can suggest one that is based on a lookbehind that will make sure there is no `EndOfLine` before the current line. It is possible since the lookbehind in .NET regex can have unlimited length:

```
(?m)(?<!^EndOfData\r?\n(?s:.*?))^(?!EndOfData\r?$)( *)(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5eEndOfData%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3fs%3a.*%3f%29%29%5e%28%3f!EndOfData%5cr%3f%24%29%28+*%29%28.*%29&i=Foo%0d%0a++++Bar%0d%0a++++Fizz%0d%0aBuzz%0d%0aEndOfData%0d%0aFoo%0d%0a++++Bar%0d%0a++++Fizz%0d%0aBuzz&o=m).

**Details**:

- `(?<!^EndOfData\r?\n(?s:.*?))` - No `EndOfData` line in front of the match can occur
- `(?!EndOfData\r?$)` - the line cannot equal `EndOfData`
- `( *)` - zero or more regular spaces (replace with `\p{Zs}` to match any horizontal whitespaces except a tab, or with a tab - `[\p{Zs}\t]`)
- `(.*)` - the rest of the line (including the CR symbol if present, use `([^\r\n]*)` if you do not want to have CR in the match group)